# Gradlefx compilation fails with dependency as3commons-logging

Tags: apache-flex, gradle, gradlefx

I created a gradle build file for a Flex swc project, which compiles successfully in intellij IDEA.

My project contains dependency

```
internal group: 'org.as3commons', name: 'as3commons-logging', version: '2.7', ext: 'swc'
```

Compilation fails, with errors like

```
....\lib\as3commons-logging-2.7.swc(org.as3commons.logging.integration:SLF4ASIntegration)

  Error: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: [com.furusystems.logging.slf4as.bindings]::ILogBinding.
```

I see that logging library indeed contains references to interfaces from other libraries, but in the IDE somehow it passes compilation and even works.

Which gradlefx option should I set?

Answer (score 1):

Solved!I changed dependency configuration from 'internal' to "merged"!

Answer (score 1):

cool :) 
Also, we have a support forum for GradleFx which you can find here: http://support.gradlefx.org/home

Comment: He did post there too: https://gradlefx.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/65-compilation-fails-with-dependency-as3commons-logging